# How to redeem a p2wsh transaction?

Tags: transactions, segregated-witness

Now we know how to redeem standard P2SH and P2PK transactions, but now since witness scripts are no longer included in transactions, how would script evaluation work under segregated witnesses?

Comment: witness scripts **are** included in transactions. but for compatibliity with old clients they are omitted while transferring to them. you should use modern client 0.13.x and testnet network for tx analysis.